# No se imprime el arreglo con sus datos completos usando DataFrame

Tags: python

en el momento me encuentro trartando de imprimir una lista con la estructura de datos DataFrame y no entinedo porque no se imprime la tabla completa. Quisiera saber como se soluciona.

```
import pandas as pd
lista=[{"ID": "0000000015", "Nombres": "Maria Luz", "Apellidos": "Lopez Lopez", "Edad": 26, "Pertenencias": ["Carro", "Casa", "Moto","Carro", "Casa", "Moto"]},
{"ID": "0000000075", "Nombres": "David David", "Apellidos": "Perez Perez", "Edad": 18, "Pertenencias": ["Carro1","Carro2", "Casa", "Moto"]},
{"ID": "1000000005", "Nombres": "Juan Carlos", "Apellidos": "Martinez Martinez", "Edad": 24, "Pertenencias": ["Moto1", "Casa1","Carro", "Casa2", "Moto2"]}]

data_frames = pd.DataFrame(lista)

print(data_frames)
```

Comment: sinceramente no se que decirte :/ todo se ve correcto

Comment: Supongo que es por el ilde que este usando, corre el script directamente en una ventana de cmd si usas windows que se adapta mejor a las visualizaciones largas o la podes estirar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay 2 maneras de hacer esto:

### Método to_string()

Si imprimimos con `print(data_frames.to_string())` se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Cambiando set_option

Pandas corta los dataframe para poder mostrarlos en una matriz que quepa en la pantalla de tu IDE o tu command line interface. Los parámetros del largo de filas y columnas que puede mostrar se pueden cambiar así:

```
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
```

Esto haría que se imprimiera así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias.